# Angular 2 HTTP GET with TypeScript: variable empty after subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs, subscribe

I am trying to call a HTTP GET method in a service, my problem is that I can't save the response properly.

in my app.component.ts:

```
marker: any;
...
this.formService.getMarker()
  .subscribe(( marker: Marker[]) => {
    this.marker = marker;
    console.log(this.marker); // I get output from db 
});
console.log(this.marker); // I get undefined
```

In my app.service.ts:

```
getMarker(){
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:3002/marker')
    .map(res => res.text());
}
```

How can I save the response from the API call Properly so that I can use it in the component?

Comment: change getMarker() as below
getMarker(){
return this.http.get('http://localhost:3002/marker')
  .map(res => res.json());
}

Comment: my variable 'marker' is still undefined after the subscribe call

Comment: First check the response from /marker by console.log

Comment: inside the subscribe i get the data with console.log, but outside the subscribe the console.log says undefined. how can i save the response properly in a variable to use it in other methods ?

Comment: this.formService.getMarker()
      .subscribe(marker => {
      this.marker = marker;
        console.log(this.marker); ----> "i get the data"
    });
    console.log(this.marker); ------> "i get undefined"

Comment: outside subscribe you wont get any data because response is yet to come.
For this we are using subscribe which means once response is get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Component({...})
   class MarkerComponent(){

        marker: any;

        getDataFromServer(){
             let _self = this;
             this.formService.getMarker()
             .subscribe(( marker: Marker[]) => {
                         _self.marker = marker;
                         _self.cotherFunction(); // this run after the response
              });
              this.otherFunction() // this run after request
        }

        otherFunction(){
          console.log(this.marker);
        }
    }
```